# line 17, column 37: Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: apex, bug

The full error I'm receiving is the following and I can't find the problem for the life if me.

> line 17, column 37: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
> setJobOperationStatus(List<Job_Operations__c>) from the type
> JobOperationHandler

I'm running a test class, but even if I call this method using the following I get the same error.

```
List<Id> jobOpIds = new List<Id>();
jobOpIds.add('a3Z1R000009L5i6UAC');
JobOperationHandler.setJobOperationStatus(jobOpIds);
```

It seems like it might be a problem w/ developer console because this was an old error when I changed the parameters from Id to Job_Operations__c object and then back again. Now I can't get it to run at all or display any logs.

```
JobOperationHandler.setJobOperationStatus(jobOpIds);

global class JobOperationHandler {
    
    //@Sam 10-19-21 v1.1.0
    //@Sam 02-24-22 v1.2.0 : Added setOperatingTimeMinutes method
    
    //set the Job Operation Status based on the completed Job Operation Inspections
    public static void setJobOperationStatus(Id[] jobOpIds) {
        //get Job Operations from Ids
        //Job_Operations__c[] jobOps = [SELECT Id, Name, Status__c FROM Job_Operations__c WHERE Id in :jobOpIds];
        
        List<Job_Operations__c> jobOpsToUpdate = new List<Job_Operations__c>();
        Job_Operation_Inspection__c[] jobOpInsps = new List<Job_Operation_Inspection__c>();
        
        //get Job Operation Inspections for each Job Op
        try {
            jobOpInsps = [SELECT Id, Type__c, Job_Operation__c FROM Job_Operation_Inspection__c WHERE Job_Operation__c = :jobOpIds];
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            jobOpInsps = null;
        }
        //check each job operation and job operation inspection to see which job op insps each job op has
        for (Id jobOpId :jobOpIds) {
            Job_Operations__c jobOp = new Job_Operations__c(Id = jobOpId);
            Boolean OpInsp = false;
            Boolean FirstArtInsp = false;
            Boolean FinishInsp = false;
            for (Job_Operation_Inspection__c jobOpInsp :jobOpInsps) {
                if (jobOpId == jobOpInsp.Job_Operation__c) {
                    switch on jobOpInsp.Type__c {
                        when 'Op Insp'{
                            OpInsp = true;
                        }
                        when '1st Article Insp' {
                            FirstArtInsp = true;
                        }
                        when 'Finish Insp' {
                            FinishInsp = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(OpInsp == true && FirstArtInsp == true && FinishInsp == true){
                    jobOp.Status__c = 'Completed';
                    jobOpsToUpdate.add(jobOp);
                }
                else if (OpInsp == true && FirstArtInsp == true && FinishInsp == false){
                    jobOp.Status__c = 'Finish Insp';
                    jobOpsToUpdate.add(jobOp);
                }
                else if (OpInsp == true && FirstArtInsp == false && FinishInsp == false) {
                    jobOp.Status__c = '1st Article Insp';
                    jobOpsToUpdate.add(jobOp);
                }
                else if (OpInsp == false && FirstArtInsp == false && FinishInsp == false) {
                    jobOp.Status__c = 'Op Insp';
                    jobOpsToUpdate.add(jobOp);
                }
        }
        update JobOpsToUpdate;
    }
    //all in minutes
    global static Decimal setJobOperationTime(Decimal flatCount, Job_Operations__c jobOp) {
        Decimal operatingTime = 0;
        Decimal setupTime = 0;
        Decimal flatChangeOverTime = 0;
        Decimal runTime = 0;
        system.debug('jobOp: ' + jobOp);
        if(jobOp.Operation__r.Setup_Time__c != 0 && jobOp.Job__r.Gang_Run_Part_Count__c != 0) {
            setupTime = jobOp.Op_Difficulty_Level__c * (jobOp.Operation__r.Setup_Time__c / jobOp.Job__r.Gang_Run_Part_Count__c);
        }
        else{
            setupTime = 0;
        }
        
        system.debug(' jobOp.Operation__r.Flat_Changeover_Time__c: '+  jobOp.Operation__r.Flat_Changeover_Time__c);
        if(jobOp.Operation__r.Flat_Changeover_Time__c != null) {
             system.debug('TRUWEjobOp.Operation__r.Flat_Changeover_Time__c: '+  jobOp.Operation__r.Flat_Changeover_Time__c);
            flatChangeOverTime = (flatCount * jobOp.Operation__r.Flat_Changeover_Time__c);
        }
        
        
        //set runTime
        switch on jobOp.Operation__r.Unit__c { 
            when 'Part' {
                runTime = jobOp.Operation__r.Run_Time__c * flatCount;
            }
            when 'Flat' {
                runTime = jobOp.Operation__r.Run_Time__c;
            }
            when 'Other' {
                runTime = getOtherRunTime(jobOp)  * flatCount;
                operatingTime = setupTime + runTime + flatChangeOverTime;
            }
            when else{
            }
        }
        
        return operatingTime;
    }
    //set run time if Operation Unit Type equals 'Other'
    private static Decimal getOtherRunTime(Job_Operations__c jobOp) {
        Decimal otherRunTime = 0; 
        Decimal partWidth = Decimal.valueOf(jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.Part_Width__c);
        Decimal partLength = Decimal.valueOf(jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.Part_Length__c);
        Decimal smallHoleCount = jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.Number_of_Small_Holes__c;
        Decimal medHoleCount = jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.Number_of_Medium_Holes__c;
        Decimal largeHoleCount = jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.Number_of_Large_Holes__c;
        Decimal substrateCohFeedTime = jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.BOM_Substrate_Coherent_Feed_Time__c;
        Decimal substrateLaserFeedTime = jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.BOM_Substrate_Laser_Feed_Time__c;
        Decimal strikeCount = jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.Number_of_Strikes__c;
        
        if (jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.Number_of_Strikes__c == null) {
            strikeCount = 0;
        }
        Decimal opRunTime = jobOp.Operation__r.Run_Time__c;
        Decimal partRowWidth = jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.Row_Width__c;
        Decimal partRowLength = jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.Row_Length__c;
        Decimal gangRunPartCount = jobOp.Job__r.Gang_Run_Part_Count__c;
        Decimal partsPerFlat = jobOp.Job__r.Part__r.Parts_Per_Flat__c;
        Decimal partCircumference = partWidth * 2 + partLength *2;
        Decimal laserMovementTime;
        Decimal cutTime;
        Decimal totalTimePerPart;
        
        switch on jobOp.Operation__r.Name {
            when 'Coherent Laser'{
                
                Decimal smallHoleCircumference = 3.14 * 0.25 * smallHoleCount; 
                Decimal medHoleCircumference = 3.14 * 1 * medHoleCount;
                cutTime = (partCircumference + smallHoleCircumference + medHoleCircumference) / substrateCohFeedTime;
                laserMovementTime= (2 + medHoleCount + smallHoleCount) * 2/60;
                totalTimePerPart = cutTime + laserMovementTime;
                
                otherRunTime =  (totalTimePerPart * partsPerFlat).round(System.roundingMode.CEILING)  ;
            }
            when 'Laser Cut', 'Laser Cut*' {
                if(substrateLaserFeedTime != 0) {
                    cutTime = (partCircumference + (15.7 * medHoleCount) + (3.14 * smallHoleCount) + (31.4 * largeHoleCount)) / substrateLaserFeedTime;                    
                }
                else {
                    cutTime = 1;
                }
                    laserMovementTime = (2 + largeHoleCount + medHoleCount + largeHoleCount) * 3.5 / 60;
                    totalTimePerPart = cutTime + laserMovementTime;
                    otherRunTime = totalTimePerPart * partsPerFlat;
            }
            when 'Turret Punch Press', 'Turret Punch Press 02' {
                otherRunTime = (strikeCount * opRunTime * 2.2) * partsPerFlat;
            }
            when 'Metal Cutting' {
                otherRunTime = partCircumference / substrateLaserFeedTime;
            }
            when 'Cut to Size' {
               otherRunTime = (partsPerFlat + 3 ) * opRunTime;
            }
            when 'Cut to Strips' {
                Decimal minRow;
                if (partRowLength > partRowWidth) {
                    minRow = partRowWidth;
                }
                else {
                    minRow = partRowLength;
                }
                otherRunTime = (minRow + 1) * opRunTime;
            }
        }
        return  otherRunTime;
    }
    @InvocableMethod(Label='Set Job Operation Time based on given number of flats')
    global static List <JobOperationTimeResult> setJobOperationTimeAction(JobOperationTimeRequest[] jobOpTimeReqs) {
        List<JobOperationTimeResult> jobOpTimeResults = new List<JobOperationTimeResult>();
        for(JobOperationTimeRequest jobOpTimeReq :jobOpTimeReqs) {
            JobOperationTimeResult jobOpTimeResult = new JobOperationTimeResult();
            jobOpTimeResult.operatingTime = setJobOperationTime(jobOpTimeReq.flatCount, jobOpTimeReq.jobOp);
            jobOpTimeResults.add(jobOpTimeResult);
        }
        return jobOpTimeResults;
    }
    global class JobOperationTimeRequest {
        @invocableVariable(required=true)
        public Job_Operations__c jobOp;
        @invocableVariable(required=true)
        public Decimal flatCount;
        
    }
    global class JobOperationTimeResult {
        @invocableVariable
        global Decimal operatingTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the class look like when viewing in the setup UI?  (i.e. not in the developer console)

Comment: Just checked. Copy and pasted from setup UI to dev console and got the same error.

Comment: have you done a compile all classes to make sure they're all still valid?

Comment: I'm dumb. There was another class with incorrect parameters types. But, I didn't know about the compile all classes button. I'm guessing that would have found it too.